# Rails render string with blank spaces in html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I do something like:

```
<%= c.title %>
```

Rails render it like this:

```
"
        Title
    "
```

This behavior isn't the same if I wrap the string with a tag. Can someone please explain me why Rails acts like this?

**UPDATE**

[Github's Repo link](https://github.com/waldyr/so_question)

Comment: Are you sure? What is the output of `'<%= c.title %>'`, or `<%= "'#{c.title}'" %>`?

Comment: The former will be just `Title` and the latter will be `"Title"`. Correct me if I am wrong. But then why waldyr is getting the result inside quotes?

Comment: You have whitespace in some other view file. For example, if this is a view template, you likely have a layout file containing the whitespace  you're seeing. The code you're showing completely out of context is functioning exactly as intended.

Comment: AFAIK there's no circumstances under which erb would add arbitrary spaces. Without the surrounding HTML I don't see how this question can be answered.

Comment: In which file u r using it?

Comment: I'm deploying on heroku and git for your analysis. Instead of downvoting the question, you can comment your issue and I will improve the question

Comment: ok give git repo link, or just tell in which file u r using this line?

Comment: There is only one view file. Start application and inspect `Whats wrong with me?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with ERB instead of Rails. When the template is processed it outputs any values from output ERB tags `(<%= %>)` to the output buffer and simply executes any other code.

Everything else is left untouched. Whitespace before and after the ERB tags is untouched. The most that you can do is to use `-` in the tags to have it strip some of the whitespace.

```
<!-- -->
<% for i in 1..10 %>
  <%= i -%>
<% end %>
<!-- -->
```

Will output

```
<!-- foo -->
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10<!-- foo -->
```

Note the two spaces that still show up before each number, take out that whitespace and it will look like one long number.

Compare this with

```
<% for i in 1..10 %>
  <%= i %>
<% end %>
```

Will output

```
<!-- -->
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
<!-- -->
```

---

Here's the output from your test page after select View Source from the context menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testapp</title>
  <link href="/assets/application-1b13569e9620782f423d4cd3ce931750.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/application-9a717ea62eac3463d689b2ba0a4e85b4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="/hfgtJZWzxaQ2d7txQMAt2b+21MWSTYcf6/2F7Pei1k=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
What&#x27;s wrong with me?

<!-- -->What&#x27;s wrong with me surrounded by html commet<!-- -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser you did this?

Comment: It's the output html source from the rails app, has nothing to do with a browser.

Comment: Wait, are you looking at the Elements tab of chrome? That has nothing to do with the output source. You can strip all spaces and newlines and that will still be formatted whatever way chrome does. Right click the page and View Source, or use wget/GET commands on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some indentation in your layout file or another file that renders this view.

Your application.html.erb may look like this :

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %> <!-- Some whitespaces at the beginning of this line -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Rails simply replaces the <%= %> tags with the value of the expression in it, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. Here's the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testapp</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="cOfMPm5S/tCHCEHkeRTeQTITAiz800s+3Q4ZgNWCNlY=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
What&#x27;s wrong with me?


</body>
</html>
```

The relevant layout section:

```
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
```

Comment: I have just noticed that only Chrome has this issue

Comment: @waldyr.ar That's what I'm using.

Comment: Can you please inspect with this [link](http://nameless-inlet-3870.herokuapp.com/) and tell me which chrome version you use?

Comment: @waldyr.ar Essentially the same rendered/inspect output. Version 25.0.1364.99 under OS X.

Comment: I'm afraid to say, but I tested with similar circumstances and it still shows wrong for me

Comment: @waldyr.ar I just don't see how that's possible if you're working w/ a clean bundle install. What version of Ruby? Rails? It's erb--it's not going to add arbitrary stuff. I used the repo as it currently is.

Comment: He's viewing the formatted version that chrome displays when you open the inspector, has nothing to do with the actual source rendered by Rails/ERB

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with you!

The solution for me is to change the file Encoding from `UTF-8` to `UTF-8 without BOM`

I'm using sinatra, glad to share with you!